# Call to a member function ERROR PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to use this tutorial to populate a Select2 drop down with data from a MySQL Database: http://www.southcoastweb.co.uk/jquery-select2-ajax-tutorial/

This is the PHP script I am using (Slightly modified from original):

```
<?php
    // setup databse connection
    require("../scripts/connect.php");

    // i have set the limit to 40 to speed up results
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT id,model FROM vehicles WHERE model LIKE :term ORDER BY model ASC LIMIT 0,40");

    // bind the value for security with the wildcard % attached.
    $result->bindvalue(':term','%'.$_GET["q"].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();

    // make sure there are some results else a null query will be returned
    if($result->rowcount() != 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"text"=>$row['id']." - ".$row['model']);
            // the text I want to show is in the form of option id - option
        }
    } else {
    // 0 results send a message back to say so.
        $answer[] = array("id"=>"0","text"=>"No Results Found..");
    }

    // finally encode the answer to json and send back the result.
    echo json_encode($answer);
```

This is the DB layout:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `carline` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
    `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `year` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    `engine` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `airconditioning` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
    `transmission` enum('Automatic','Manual') NOT NULL,
    `drive` enum('2WD','4WD') NOT NULL,
    `designation` enum('Passenger','Commercial') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

And this is the Error I am recieving:

> [08-Feb-2014 18:28:06 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Notice: Undefined
>   variable: db in /Users/.../app/scripts/serviceplan_values.php on line
>   6 [08-Feb-2014 18:28:06 Pacific/Auckland] PHP Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /Users/.../app/scripts/serviceplan_values.php on line 6

Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8706](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642097/500-internal-server-error-jquery-js8706)

Comment: `call to a member function on a non object` typically means for you that you think the `$db` variable has been properly set, but its really just `null`. do a `var_dump($db)` to verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is most probably in `connect.php`, where you need to set the `$db` variable.

Comment: Ah hah that makes sense, the tut said he wouldn't cover that, what do you think I would need to set it as?

Comment: Do you think you could help?

Comment: Edit your question to include your `connect.php` (**make sure to delete the password and other sensitive information first!**); then I hope I can help.